# Unable to get PyYAML objects to represent correctly

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am using PyYaml to regenerate a YAML file but I have unwanted angle brackets around the dumped output:

Source YAML file:

```
 Outputs:
  HarvestApi:
    Description: URL for application
    Value: !Ref LocationRef
    Export:
      Name: HarvestApi
```

and the python file should just parse and then dump the YAML:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import yaml
import sys

class RefTag(yaml.YAMLObject):
  yaml_tag = u'Ref'
  def __init__(self, text):
    self.text = text
  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s( text=%r)" % ( self.__class__.__name__, self.text)
  @classmethod
  def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
    return RefTag(node.value)
  @classmethod
  def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag, data.text)
yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor('!Ref', RefTag.from_yaml)
yaml.SafeDumper.add_multi_representer(RefTag, RefTag.to_yaml)

yaml_list = None
with open("./yaml-test.yml", "r")  as file:  
  try:
    yaml_list = yaml.safe_load(file)
  except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
    print ("--", exc)
    sys.exit(1)

print (yaml.dump(yaml_list, default_flow_style=False))
```

But instead outputs this:

```
Outputs:
  HarvestApi:
    Description: URL for application
    Export:
      Name: HarvestApi
    Value: !<Ref> 'LocationRef'
```

Those extra angle brackets around the Ref object are what I need to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your tag doesn't start with an exclamation
mark. Just adding that will give you the expected output. For
reference see the PyYAML example for the
[`Monster`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#constructors-representers-resolvers)
class.

The additional problematic things are:

- the FAQ on yaml.org has stated since Sep 2006 that the recommended file extension for
  YAML files is `.yaml`
- PyYAML dumping (and loading) has a streaming interface, but has a
  much abused convenience option to leave out the stream, after which
  the output is written to a memory buffer that is returned as a string.
  Using that to then stream out the resulting string using:

  ```
  print(dump(yaml_list, ...))
  ```

  is slow and memory inefficient.
- You register your loader and dumper for `RefTag` on the
  `SafeLoader`, which is good as there is no need to go unsafe with
  the default PyYAML `Loader` and `Dumper`. But then you call
  `yaml.dump()` instead of `yaml.safe_dump()`. The former works, but
  using the latter is better, as it will complain about non-registered
  objects in your data structure (if there would be any of course, not
  with the input, you are now using).

So change things to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import yaml
import sys

class RefTag(yaml.YAMLObject):
  yaml_tag = u'!Ref'
  def __init__(self, text):
    self.text = text
  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s( text=%r)" % ( self.__class__.__name__, self.text)
  @classmethod
  def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
    return RefTag(node.value)
  @classmethod
  def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag, data.text)

yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor('!Ref', RefTag.from_yaml)
yaml.SafeDumper.add_multi_representer(RefTag, RefTag.to_yaml)

yaml_list = None
with open("./yaml-test.yaml", "r")  as file:  
  try:
    yaml_list = yaml.safe_load(file)
  except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
    print ("--", exc)
    sys.exit(1)

yaml.safe_dump(yaml_list, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False)
```

which gives:

```
Outputs:
  HarvestApi:
    Description: URL for application
    Export:
      Name: HarvestApi
    Value: !Ref 'LocationRef'
```